# Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping (automapper 6.1.1)

Tags: c#, object, exception, mapping, automapper

This is what I am trying to do and getting exception on this very line:

```
Mapper.Map<CreditCard>(cardVM);
```

While other mappings are working perfectly but these two entities aren't
here's models of both :

```
[Serializable]
    public class CreditCard : BaseEntity
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string BankToken { get; set; }
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }


[Serializable]
    public class CreditCardVM
    {
        public Guid? UID { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string BankToken { get; set; }
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethodUId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; } 
    }
```

But still getting exception "Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping"

Comment: Hi, can you past the full error and stacktrace?

Comment: The full error message is telling you exactly what cannot be mapped.

Comment: can you post exact inner exception

Comment: thanks , but I got the solution , I was missing Createmap that has to be inherited with Automapper.Profile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys , but here is what I missed .

```
public class CreditCardAutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public CreditCardAutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Data.Entities.CreditCard, CreditCardVM>();
        }
    }
```

And it starts working :)

Answer (score 0):

What about checking Automapper configurations initiation, maybe your mappings configutations are not initialized.

So, check the application start configuration in your startup project, like in web application you have to check "application_start in Global.asax"

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AutoMapperConfigurator.Initialize();
}
```